# Document feed limit

Tags: java, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

Is there a limit to the number of entries returned in a DocumentListFeed?  I'm getting 100 results, and some of the collections in my account are missing.

How can I make sure I get all of the collections in my account?

```
DocsService service = new DocsService(APP_NAME);
service.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
String feedUrl = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/-/folder?v=3&showfolders=true&showroot=true");
DocumentLisFeed feed = service.getFeed(feedUrl, DocumentListFeed.class);    
List<DocumentListEntry> entries = feed.getEntries();
```

The size of entries is 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single request to the Documents List feed by default returns 100 element, but you can configure that value by setting the `?max-results` query parameter.

Regardless, in order to retrieve all documents and files you should always take into account sending multiple requests, one per page, as explained in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#getting_all_pages_of_documents_and_files

Please also note that it is now recommended to switch to the newer Google Drive API, which interacts with the same resources and has complete documentation and sample code in multiple languages, including Java:

https://developers.google.com/drive/

Comment: The last I heard, the Google Drive API is only available to Chrome Web apps.  The rest of your answer is great.

Comment: The Chrome installation requirement has been removed with version 2 of the Drive API. As reference, check this video for a 10-minute tutorial on how to create a command-line Drive app in Python: https://developers.google.com/live/shows/ahNzfmdvb2dsZS1kZXZlbG9wZXJzcg4LEgVFdmVudBiVlJoDDA/

Comment: Can you access the Drive API from web services?

Comment: You can access it from any source that can send HTTP requests

Answer (score 0):

You can call
    feed.getNextLink().getHref()
to get a URL that you an form another feed with.  This can be done until the link is null, at which point all the entries have been fetched.